# Django .save(using='...') correct database name

Tags: django

My Django settings.py contains the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { # several settings omitted
               'NAME': 'myproject', 'HOST': 'localhost', },
    'other': { 'NAME': 'other', 'HOST': 'else.where', }
}
```

I now want to fetch some objects from the *other* DB and save it to *default* like so:

```
things = Thing.objects.using('other').raw('SELECT code,created FROM other.otherapp_bigthing WHERE created>...')
# 'code' is a unique string in other and PK of the Thing model
for t in things:
     t.save(using='default')
```

This gives me

```
ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'other.myapp_thing' doesn't exist")
```

which is a correct observation, however, by the [documentation of the `using` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save) I expected the records to be saved to `myproject.myapp_thing`. Why is the database name still taken from the `other` configuration when I explicitly advised it to use `default`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>I eventually worked around this by making a raw insert (`connections['default'].cursor().execute('INSERT INTO myproject.myapp_thing (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...')` but still wanted to know why the question's code does not work.</sub>

The problem was that the `Thing` model contained another field: next to the `code` CharField/PK and `created` date (in my use case actually `last_accessed`) there was another date (think `modified`) with `default=None, null=True` and I assumed the default would be used if I do not explicitly include in the original raw query.

Apparently, this assumption was wrong and Django tried, on `t.save`, to look up a value for `modified` in the DB it originally came from -- and failed, since it came from a raw SQL query.

If I include `,NULL AS 'modified'` in the raw SQL query the original error goes away  <sub>but I still cannot reasonably use Django logic for my use case since `t.save(using='default')` would, for existing things, update `last_accessed` *and* overwrite the `modified` date with NULL, which I do not want, and `t.save(using='default', update_fields=['last_accessed'])` would [force an update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) and thus fail for new things</sub>.